# Avoid cookies pop up window inside iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, popup

I have an iframe that displays live prices of stock market. My problem is that when i load my page, this iframe shows a pop up window for cookies policy.
Is there anyway to avoid this window completely (or select "accept" in background) so that this iframe will directly show stock prices?

I found some information about sandbox option but could not go deeper with that

My website is the following and the iframe is on the down-left

https://grbusinessforum.com/

("Αποδέχομαι" is the button of "Accept cookies")

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sandboxing the iframe can prevent all JS from running inside it, but that would probably break the page in other ways.

There's nothing you can do from outside the frame.

You'd need to change the page inside the frame instead. You could add a query string to the URL that it uses to disable the tracking cookies by default, or use `postMessage` to send a message into the frame that code there uses to remove the cookie prompt.

Of course, this will need the cooperation of the people who control the site you are displaying in the frame … but if they are happy for you to show their content on your page that shouldn't be too much of a problem, should it?

Comment: Thanks
Do you know if there is anyway to save cookies so that if some user of my site accepts the cookies inside the iframe, this pop up will not appear in the future?
This way the pop up will appear only once, much better than appearing every time someone visits my site

Comment: Saving cookies is, unless the browser is configured to block third-party cookies, the default in a frame. Whether or not that causes the message to show is up to that site.